# iOS Leaderboard: Rank users on overall shortest time

Tags: iphone, ios, game-center

I want to be able to rank users based on how quick they have completed each level. I want this to be an overall leaderboard I.e. shortest overall time for all levels.

The problem here is that for each level completed the totally completion time goes up. But I want to ensure that the leaderboard takes that into account so that a user having completed 10 levels will rank more highly than someone with only 1 completed level.

How can I create some kind of score based on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before submitting the time to leader board.

You could perform a modulation on the total time by the number of levels completed, then for each level completed reduce it by a set amount so people who complete all levels with the same average time will score better then people with the same average time but with fewer levels.

My Preferred Method:

Or you could express it with a score value.
level complete = 1,000.
Each level has a set time limit bonus, the longer you take the less bonus u get.
eg

> I Complete the level in 102 secs Goal time is 120 secs
>
> I get 1,000 points for completion and 1,500 points for each second
>   that i beat the Goal time for.
>
> This way i will get 1,000 + (18* 1,500) = 28,000 points
>
> Next guy completes in 100 secs
>
> He Gets 1,000 + (20*1,500) = 31,000 points

Answer (score 1):

I suggest adding a default amount of time to the total for each incomplete level. So, say, if a player beats a new level in 3 minutes, that replaces a 10 minute placeholder time, and they 'save' 7 minutes from the total.

Without that kind of trick, the iPhone has no provision for multi-factor rankings.

Answer (score 0):

Leaderboard scores in GameKit have to be expressed as a single number (see this [section](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/LeaderBoards/LeaderBoards.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH6-SW13) of the GameKit Programming Guide), so that won't be possible.

Your best bet would be to just have a completion time leaderboard for people who have completed all the levels, and maybe another leaderboard (or a few) for people who have completed a smaller number of levels.